# React Use Function In Javascript Object

Tags: jquery, reactjs, highcharts

General question for React interacting with javascript libraries. How can I use a function defined in React inside a javascript object.  Is there a jQuery or pure react way?

Example:

I am using a highcharts-react-official library that is just a react wrapper around a JS library.

You would use it like:

```
const options = {
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: (e) => { 
                                console.log(e.point.name); console.log(e.point.category); console.log(e.point.y);  
                                this.handleFilter(); //NEED TO CALL THIS FUNCTION
                              }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

class ChartComponent extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                someData: []            
            };
            this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this); //doesn't seem to work
        }

        handleFilter() {
           console.log('Filter Triggered');
           //EDIT -- Needs to be able to setState of this component here:
           this.setState({someData: []});
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                  <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={options}
                  />
                </div>
            );
        }
}
```

How can I use `handleFilter` within that object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach would be to add the click option inside react component. You can get the global `options` value from JS, then add the click event callback inside React component.

Something this way:

```
var options = {}; // Any global config can go here

class ChartComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      someData: []            
    };
    this.handleFilter = this.handleFilter.bind(this);
  }

  handleFilter() {
    console.log('Filter Triggered');
    this.setState({someData: []});
  }

  getChartOptions() {
    // Can add any other config here

    if(!options.hasOwnProperty('plotOptions'))
        options.plotOptions = {}

    if(!options.plotOptions.hasOwnProperty('series'))
        options.plotOptions.series = {}

    if(!options.plotOptions.series.hasOwnProperty('events'))
        options.plotOptions.events = {}

    options.plotOptions.series.events = {
      click: (e) => { 
        console.log(e.point.name);
        console.log(e.point.category);
        console.log(e.point.y);  

        this.handleFilter();
      }
    };

    return options;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={this.getChartOptions()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

PS: Recently, I've implemented the same using HightChart JS library instead of its official React library and it works !!

Comment: Hmm.. where would the initial options with the series and data etc go?

Comment: @HoosierCoder As I said, you can add any global config while initiating the `options`. If those are not global (rather component specific config), then just add that in `getChartOptions()` function. [Edited the answer as well].

Comment: I see..  just gives me a blank chart no matter where I define initial options.. `getChartOptions` doesn't need a return?

Comment: Yeah, it should. Added that in the answer.

Comment: That still returns a blank chart.. I think it's reading getChartOptions as a blank {}. Did you say you implemented a callback function with just the plain JS version within react?

Comment: One more thing which was missing is to add `()` after `this.getChartOptions`. Edited the answer.

Comment: Very nice. That calls the function and is able to set the state. Any idea why if you just set the `{options}` and have a callback there, it doesn't recognize the function. But setting the options to a `getChartOptions()` allows it to see `this.handleFilter()`?

Comment: The `option` defined in your question is out of the `ChartComponent` class thus it's `this` was different from `this` inside the React component.

Comment: You know, I instantiated `options` inside ChartComponent, and it still only worked with your function not just `options`. Then, implemented the plain JS version without the official react-highcharts library, and everything works as expected. Also, renders faster. Looks like they did a poor job on implementing this lib. Thanks for your help, you're spot on.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of the class and call the function on it.

```
const chartClassInst = new ChartComponent();
const handleFilterFunction = chartClassInst.handleFilter;

const options = {
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    point: {
                        events: {
                            click: (e) => { 
                                console.log(e.point.name); console.log(e.point.category); console.log(e.point.y);  
                                handleFilterFunction(); 
                              }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

Comment: When I use this approach, in the `handleFilter()` `this.setState({someData: []})` errors out with: "Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted." Is there a way to setState in this function?

Comment: Can't you put 'options' inside your component itself in the render function.

render() {
            const options = { ... };
            return (
                <div>
                  <HighchartsReact
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    options={options}
                  />
                </div>
            );
        }

Comment: Just tried it. Same error.. It only pops up on the actual click event